# Can't make POST request using Fetch in React Native (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, fetch

I am very new to React native and have run into lots of problems with my POST request and done lots of research on the Internet to make this work, however I keep getting "undefined" all the time.

This is all my code in `index.android.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Alert, StyleSheet, View, TextInput, TouchableHighlight, Text } from 'react-native';   

var DroverDaniel = React.createClass({

  _onPressButtonPOST: function() {

    let myBody = JSON.stringify({"partner[email]": "daniel.smith@gmail.com", "partner[password]": "mypassword"});

    let myInit = { method: 'POST', cache: 'default', body: myBody };

    fetch("https://drover-test.herokuapp.com/app_partners/sign_in", myInit).then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(function(j) {    
      Alert.alert("POST Response", "Response Body -> " + j.api_token)
      console.log(j);
    }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    // Alert.alert("Response Body -> " +err);
    });

  },



  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>      
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButtonPOST} style={styles.button}>
      <Text>POST</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
      );
  },

});

  var styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
     flex: 1,
     flexDirection: 'row',
     justifyContent: 'center',
     alignItems: 'center',
     backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
   },
   button: {
     backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
     padding: 10,
     marginRight: 5,
     marginLeft: 5,
   }
 });

AppRegistry.registerComponent('DroverDaniel', () => DroverDaniel);
```

I have tested the API in Postman and this works - this is what I should get for this simple login POST request:

```
{
  "id": 40,
  "email": "daniel@some-email.com",
  "first_name": "Daniel",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "api_token": "ffZWYC8Z4zD3-c4y9mT3"
}
```

Unfortunately the .catch does not show any errors in the "console" - I'm assuming the terminal server I'm running. And trying to output the error in the Alert box, also yields no results.

I've been stuck on this pretty much all day, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i've tried your code and it works perfectly , i got invalid user name or password because i don't have an account .

Comment: Ok thanks very much Ahmed, maybe it's a problem with the way the API has been set up. You can sign up here: https://drover-test.herokuapp.com/partners/sign_in and test with your own credentials. It would be great if you could verify it to make sure there is nothing wrong with my code.

Comment: @daneasterman It would help if you post the exact error. Where are you getting undefined error? React native should give a line number where this is occurring

Comment: Hi @coderhacker , there is no error in the console shown by React, it's just the data returned is always shown as undefined when "printed" in the alert window